# Bluetooth module PCB layout

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, layout, bluetooth-low-energy

On my PCB, I have the Bluetooth module (ANNA-B112) on the top layer. Due to space constraints, I had to put some components on the Bottom layer of the PCB beneath the Bluetooth module. The main components are one LDO and a main BUCK.

I will be using a U.FL-R-SMT connector to connect an external antenna to the Bluetooth module.

Will there be any interference issues if I place component(bottom layer) beneath the Bluetooth module(top layer), even if I use an external antenna?

Please check the attached picture of my PCB layout.[image]

Comment: Where is the converters inductor located and is it shielded?  I would not normally expect a LDO to have much interaction as long the power is decoupled.

Comment: @GB-AE7OO The bucks power inductor is located on the right side of the circled buck, it has huge red pad labeled 1.

Comment: Humm..  So I"m guessing it's un-shielded, as I can't recall ever seeing a vertical inductor that was shielded.  I'm not sure of the scale, but how big of a current loop does that buck have? And is the LDO feed by the buck?  If so I'm confused.

Comment: Is there an internal ground plane between the top and bottom side? Switching portion of buck converter should all be on bottom side. Also noise depends on how noisy buck converter is. I like Silent Switcher series from Analog Devices, or you can additional filtering to buck input and output.